# Call of overloaded is ambigous

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, overloading

I'm working on a compiler project. And when I look through some code on GitHub, I come across a problem when compile the source code. The error is:

`call of overloaded ‘newast(<anonymous enum>, NULL, _ast*&, NULL)’ is ambiguous`

and the related fucntions are `_ast* newast(_action, char*, _ast*, _ast*)` and `_ast* newast(_action, int, _ast*, _ast*)`

I don't know why here will have such an ambiguity. And the related code in .y file is followed.

```
| IDENTIFIER '(' ')' { $$ = newast(_call, $1, NULL, NULL); }
        | IDENTIFIER '(' expr ')' { $$ = newast(_call, $1, newast(_dummy, NULL, $3, NULL), NULL); }
        | IDENTIFIER '(' expr ',' expr ')' { $$ = newast(_call, $1, newast(_dummy, NULL, $3, $5), NULL); }
        | IDENTIFIER '(' expr ',' expr ',' expr ')' { $$ = newast(_call, $1, newast(_dummy, NULL, $3, $5), newast(_dummy, NULL, $7, NULL)); }
```

Comment: There's a good question hidden in here somewhere, but you really should sort out which details are relevant to your problem and which aren't.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between the two overloaded methods are the char* and int parameters. In the supplied code, most of the methods are calling newast() with NULL as the second parameter, which is ambiguous. The compiler can implicitly cast NULL to either an int or char*, so it's not sure what to do.

You need to be more explicit. Pass something other than NULL or explicitly cast the NULL to one of the types. For example:

newast(_action, (char*)NULL, ...

Comment: If the other overload is desired, just type `0` instead of `NULL`. Don't go for `(int)NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem in C++03. A constant expression that evaluates to zero (such as `0`) is both an integer and a pointer (more precisely, the null pointer constant). Since NULL is defined as such an expression, it acts as both an integer and a pointer too.

Most often NULL is defined as 0L, which means it is not exactly an int, and a conversion is required when you pass it to a function that expects an `int`. A conversion is also required when you pass it to a function that expects a pointer.

Consequently, if you have an overloaded function that accepts either an `int` or a pointer, and call it with a NULL argument, neither of the two is an exact match, so neither can be preferred, and the call is ambiguous.

If you can use C++11, prefer `nullptr` over NULL, as `nullptr` is *only* a pointer and not an integer. Otherwise, use `static_cast<char*>(NULL)`. Better yet, use `std::string`.

To select the other overload, use `0`. It exactly matches `int`, so the `int` overload will be preferred over the `char*` one.